# Не изменяется App.config при добавлении сервиса WCF C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf

Такая ситуация, создал контракт в виде библиотеки, создал реализацию в виде консольного приложения (хост). Сбилдил все. Запускаю хост, в клиенте добавляю сылку на сервис. Сервис находится, видны метаданные (все методы контракта), но при добавлении сервиса почему то не изменяется App.config клиента и соответственно я не могу далее работать с сервисом. 
Конфигурация сервиса:

```
 <system.serviceModel>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="VideoBroadCastingData">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<services>
  <service name="VideoBroadcastingService.VideoBroadCastingData" behaviorConfiguration="VideoBroadCastingData">
    <endpoint name="videoData" 
              address="http://192.168.1.162:8001/IVideoBroadcastingContract/"
              binding="netHttpBinding"
              contract="ILShowService.VideoBroadCastingRepository.IVideoBroadcastingContract"/>
    <endpoint name="VideoBroadcastingService.VideoBroadCastingData" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.162:8001/IVideoBroadcastingContract/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: App.config клиента]

Answer (score 1):

Возможно проблема в настройках конфигурации при добавлении сервиса через *Add Service Reference*. Тут есть кнопка <kbd>Advanced...</kbd> - нажмите на нее.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

там в открывшемся окне будет чек-бокс <kbd>Reuse types in referenced assemblies</kbd> - его нужно снять и после этого добавить ссылку на сервис в проект.

Либо есть еще второй вариант, если это не поможет <kbd>Reuse types in referenced assemblies</kbd>, там же внутри ,<kbd>Advanced...</kbd> есть кнопка <kbd>Add Web Reference</kbd> - попробуйте жмакнуть ее.

Полезная ссылка: [Visual Studio does not generate app.config content when “Add service reference”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12034326/5275890)

Comment: Спасибо, возьму на заметку. На самом деле проблема крылась в том, что в модели был тип данных Bitmap. А он по моему не знанию - не сериализуемый объект.

Comment: @JDo да, есть такое... я года два назад разрабатывал WCF сервисы и там была беда, когда всунули не сериализуемый тип, потом обновили контракты, а там нифига не обновилось... долго искали

Comment: Вот и я пол дня искал, хотя сам же на свои грабли наступил, по незнанию =) А вот такой момент, если я в самом хосте создам конструктор, я смогу его дергать в клиенте?

Comment: @JDo насколько я помню, вроде бы нет. Там дергается конструктор по умолчанию без параметров... Но, возможно, я просто чего-то не знаю